# Vertically aligning SVG radio buttons

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm expecting the SVGs and the radio buttons to be `vertical-align: middle`, and for the `viewBox="0 0 100 100"` of the SVGs to fill vertically the space available in their containing DIV, itself fitting vertically its containing DIV and shrink-wrapping horizontally the RBs and SVGs.

[image: radio buttons, SVGs, and two DIVS]

```css
.box {
    border: 3px solid grey; border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%; height: 100px; padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.label-container {
    height: 100%;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
}
.radio_buttons {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
.rb-icons {
    height: 100%;

    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="box header">
    <div class="box label-container">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="circlerect" class="radio-buttons"
                id="circ" value="foo" checked>
            <img class="icons" src='https://svgshare.com/i/GLu.svg'>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="circlerect" class="radio-buttons"
                id="rect" value="bar">
            <img class="icons" src='https://svgshare.com/i/GMr.svg'>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Would you mind changing the src of your image into an embed SVG to work in snippet?

Comment: I'm asking this because we don't really see what's the problem... In the first snippet, it's aligned fine..

Comment: https://svgur.com/

Comment: Note that the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.box {
    border: 3px solid grey; border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%; height: 100px; padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.box.header {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.label-container {
    height: 100%;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    width: auto;
}
.label-container label {
    height: 100%;
}
.label-container img {
  height: 100%;
}
.label-container .icons {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.radio-buttons {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
.rb-icons {
    height: 100%;

    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="box header">
    <div class="box label-container">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="circlerect" class="radio-buttons"
                id="circ" value="foo" checked>
            <img class="icons" src='https://svgshare.com/i/GLu.svg' />
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="circlerect" class="radio-buttons"
                id="rect" value="bar">
            <img class="icons" src='https://svgshare.com/i/GMr.svg' />
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Something like this?

Comment: Unfortunately the magic number `70px` means that this only works for the square icon. Any other aspect ratio (such as the one now in the question) fails. Hence it appears that the settings `height: 100%` are ignored. Why?

Comment: Here, I put height 100% to the label to limit its size. Note: lots of blanks are caused by the padding around and blank in your SVG. But's it's easy to fix.